# Managing security context constraints

Tags: kubernetes, version-control, openshift, redhat-containers

I have a default scc restricted in a cluster. I created another scc which has readOnlyRootFilesystem = true. I have applied this scc with a service account on one namespace. However I can still create files in /tmp in a pod. The readOnlyRootFilesystem= true does not work. I think it has something to do with the priorities between the default scc and the scc I created. Is there any solution for this? This is my scc file and the command I have used.

```
allowHostPorts: false
priority: null
requiredDropCapabilities:
  - KILL
  - MKNOD
  - SETUID
  - SETGID
allowPrivilegedContainer: false
runAsUser:
  type: MustRunAsRange
users: []
allowHostDirVolumePlugin: false
allowHostIPC: false
seLinuxContext:
  type: MustRunAs
readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/description: restricted SCC + read-only FS
  name: restricted-new
fsGroup:
  type: MustRunAs
groups: []
kind: SecurityContextConstraints
defaultAddCapabilities: null
supplementalGroups:
  type: RunAsAny
volumes:
  - configMap
  - downwardAPI
  - emptyDir
  - persistentVolumeClaim
  - projected
  - secret
allowHostPID: false
allowHostNetwork: false
allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
apiVersion: security.openshift.io/v1
allowedCapabilities: null


`$`oc create -f restricted-new.yaml
`$`oc adm policy add-scc-to-user readonly -z ro-default -n <PROJECT>
`$`oc create sa ro-default -n  <PROJECT>
`$`touch tmp/aaa.txt
```

Comment: This in not sufficient, can you edit your question and add the yaml manifest files